# SIM7600 MQTT CONNECTION TO shiftr.io broker

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am trying to use SIM7600 MQTT command to publish and subscribe to shiftr.io broker.

I have not been able to get pass stage of connecting to broker.

I use this
AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,"tcp://instance.cloud.io:1883",90,1,"username","token"

I get this error code.
+CMQTTCONNECT:  0, 25

Of which code 25 indicate DNS error

Comment: I doubt that `username` is actually a valid user name ... same with `token`

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question with "DNS error".

The domain name that you're using, `instance.cloud.io`, is currently not valid. You can verify this quite simply by searching the web for any web site that looks up domain names for you and searching for that domain name.

In this case, "instance" is most likely a placeholder for the correct name. You need to go back to whatever tutorial or instructions you were following for this and use the correct name for this to work.

Comment: The "instance " is the name i gave. I used the same pattern to pub/sub using SIM800L. But not witj SIM7600. So i am sure the issue is with understanding MQTT stack in SIM7600.